# How can I combine a INDEX, SMALL, ROW and MATCH function in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have the following function that works well however the data it returns isn't what I want.

```
=IF(COLUMNS($R$2:R2)<=VLOOKUP($A2,[Sample.xls]Sheet1!$I$2:$K$27,3,FALSE),INDEX([Sample.xls]Sheet1!$G$2:$G$116,SMALL(IF([Sample.xls]Sheet1!$B$2:$B$116=VLOOKUP($A2,[Sample.xls]Sheet1!$I$2:$K$27,1,FALSE),ROW([Sample.xls]Sheet1!$B$2:$B$116)-ROW([Sample.xls]Sheet1!$B$2)+1),COLUMNS($R$2:R2))),0)
```

If I use a separate function such as the one below, it gives me the data but not the validation that is in other function. How can I combine both these functions?

```
=INDEX([Sample.xls]Sheet1!$G$2:$G$116,MATCH(D2,[Sample.xls]Sheet1!$C$2:$C$116,0))
```

**EDIT**

The sample data looks like

```
Column1      Column2      Column3      Column4      Column5      Column6      Column7      Column8      Column9

   1      Label        System       Name         Total        GB           Available     GB          Server
   1      Label        System       Name         Total        GB           Available     GB          Server
   1      Label        System       Name         Total        GB           Available     GB          Server
```

I am then taking portions of that data e.g. Total once I match the label in the resulting worksheet which has the corresponding labels. The label has duplicate values e.g. Windows

Comment: hi, can you provide sample data and sample result. thanks.

Comment: @L42 - I have included sample data. The result is a single value e.g. 2.5

Comment: You are referencing a column `B` and `R`... but only show 9 columns. Something is missing in your example? "the data it returns is not what I want". What is it returning? Can you make it so we can actually replicate your problem? Where is this `2.5` coming from?

Comment: It would help if you included, in your own words, what you are trying to accomplish. Along the lines of "look up all values in column B that are less than x; sum them; look up the result in table starting in column R; ..." - except that is not what you are doing, obviously.

Comment: @Floris - The value `B` is a reference to a different worksheet and `R` refers to the cell in which the data is meant to be display. The data being returned is not the right value.

Comment: @Floris - I followed the example at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=132ZdpxBm1U and now am attempting to use `MATCH`.

Comment: Well I just watched that video and I can't relate it to what you are doing. You are going to have to make your question a lot clearer. "The label has duplicate values e.g. Windows"??? Sorry - don't get it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38757/discussion-between-peanutsmonkey-and-floris)

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey From your deleted question, I uploaded a spreadsheet [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23298677/PeanutsMonkey.xlsx). I have put the formulae you were using in the spreadsheet as well in the sheet called 'Free'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our chat, I think you are trying to do the following:

> ```
> Given two different values (labels) corresponding to two different columns, 
> sum the data in a third column.
> ```

This is like a "composite SUMIF" if I understand correctly. In this case, what you would like to do is create an array of `0`s and `1`s corresponding to the rows you want to include/exclude, then do a `SUMPRODUCT` with the column you want to sum.

Now we can use an ARRAY FORMULA to generate such an array.  Here is a simple example: assume these cells are `A1:C6`:

```
label   system   space
 one     a          1
 one     b          2
 one     a          4
 two     b          8
 two     a         16
```

Now we can create a "compound summary table" looking at both "label" and "system" as follows (assume these start with `label` in cell `A9`:

```
label   system  total space
 one       a        5
 one       b        2
 two       a       16 
 two       b        8
```

The formula you use in `C10` is

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF($A$2:$A$6=A10,1,0)*IF($B$2:$B$6=B10,1,0),$C$2:$C$6)
```

Which you enter as an array formula (CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER). You then drag it to cells C11-13. This performs the calculation as I interpreted it. You can embellish from here.

Let me know if I interpreted this correctly?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. The only drawback is if there are multiple instances of a or b, the space for each of them is taken as a total. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple instances"? That's what we have here... I assume that was on purpose. If not - then what would you like / expect the result to be in the case above (where I am aggregating on two columns, so `one a` has a result of `5` (`1 + 4`).

Comment: Sorry for not being explicit. There are multiple instances of the labels but in the instance there are multiple instances of a system for a given label, I don't want the values being combined. Is there a way to treat these separately?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey I think that things will get much much clearer if you can provide a sample spreadsheet with some values as close to what you have as possible. Otherwise, I don't think you'll be getting what you want or we'll understand what you're trying to describe. Try upload one on [ge.tt](http://ge.tt).

Comment: @Jerry is right. In the above instance, what do you want to show - and how. Do you want the values in separate columns? Do you want two rows? Is there another column we could use that makes the systems unique (e.g. "system ID"). But if there is no aggregating at all, why don't we just show the entire table? Is there a "look up a specific row from my table" where "specific row" actually is matching multiple criteria? I thought I understood but I'm all confused again. How do you want to use this in the end...